# Sublime Text 3 Python not building on latest version of save file

Tags: python, sublimetext3, read-eval-print-loop

To give an extremely simple example, lets say I run this:

```
import numpy
```

but I remember I want to name numpy np, so I go back to my script and tell it to build the following:

```
import numpy as np
```

if I then run the following in my console:

```
x=np.random.rand()
```

I will get an error saying that sublime text has no idea what np is. If I manually save before running the code, I get the same error. The only way to get sublime text to understand to run the updated code is to reload the file. This makes using Python in the current build of Sublime Text tedious at best and absolutely catastrophic at worst. I've only noticed this since the most recent build. Is there a new setting I need to change somewhere? If this is just how Sublime is, is it possible to revert to a previous build?

Comment: I've ran into this before if I open a file for editing then move it to another folder. Sublime is still working on the original cached document and doesn't realize you have moved the new document. Closing and reopening the file resolves this issue because Sublime is now looking in the correct location.

Comment: I haven't moved my programs to another folder, but for some reason Sublime is still going off the old cached version. Closing and reopening works, but sucks. I don't want to have to save, close and reopen every time I make a minor change to my code. If I'm debugging code that becomes a nightmare. This wasn't an issue before the latest update; is there any way to get it to not look at the cached version, or to revert to an old version of Sublime?